# How to define a JTextfield from another method?

Tags: java, swing, browser, actionlistener, final

I am making a browser, and i am creating the browser and how it looks in the main function, but in order to call the `actionListener` i need to put it in a method that is not `static`, but when i put the `actionListener` in a separate method then it asks me to make it `final` where it already is in the `main` method?

CODE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class browserPannel extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        JFrame browser = new JFrame("A Nun In A Weelchair");
        browser.setSize(1000,700);
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browser.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        browser.pack();
        browser.setVisible(true);

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        final JEditorPane htmlc = new JEditorPane();
        htmlc.setBackground(Color.red);
        htmlc.setEditable(true);
        htmlc.setContentType("text/html");

        final JTextField url = new JTextField(20);

        url.setSize(890,30);
        url.setVisible(true);

        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setSize(75,30);
        send.setVisible(true);


        header.add(url, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        header.add(send);
        browser.getContentPane().add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        browser.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(htmlc));
    }
    public void loader(JFrame browser, JTextField url, JEditorPane htmlc, JPanel header, JButton send, String[] arg)
    {

        url.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionCommand());
                    System.out.println("action performed");
                }
            }
            );

    }

    private void loadHtml(JEditorPane htmlc, JTextField url, String link)
    {
        try{
            htmlc.setPage(link);
            url.setText(link);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ops sorry could not fined Virgine Mobile");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

the command line compiler keeps giving me these error saying it needs to be declared `final`, but i already have it declared final in the main class?

CMD MESSAGE:

```
browserPannel.java:49: error: local variable htmlc is accessed from within inner
 class; needs to be declared final
                                        loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionComm
and());
                                                 ^
browserPannel.java:49: error: local variable url is accessed from within inner c
lass; needs to be declared final
                                        loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionComm
and());
                                                        ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Your code is mostly located in the static main method where it does not belong. That method should be for creating your initial objects and then starting them and little else. Instead, give your class some instance fields, some instance methods, and create a real OOP-compliant class. Then in main create an instance of this class and display it. You want your main to be simple, something like: `new MyGui().setVisible(true);`

Comment: oh i did that, but the main method must be static, and if it is static i get errors with my `actionListener`, it says the the `actionListener` is being over written with a static function. now to avoid those errors i put the `actionListener` in another method wich is not a static method so then i can use the `actonListener`.

Comment: `"... why not make the program run everything in main, then go to the loader for the actionListener, but you said make an instance."` Because you'll be in the static realm, and will lose all the advantages of object-oriented programming, and none of your code will be accessable in the class itself. You might as code in QBasic or WATFOR.

Comment: `"i am the programer who is pretty knew and fetches what he needs to program with, so i dont know lots of things, yet i know many things. what do you mean by instance?"`, you will probably have a much better coding experience if you go through a basic Java textbook, at least the first 5 chapters, before trying to create complex Swing programs. The concept of an instance or an object is one of the first things that this will teach you.

Comment: Separate you code into layers of responsibility.  Connect these layers together through the use of models and listeners.  Don't blob the whole thing together and expect it work...well..

Answer (score 0):

The relevant parameters of your method, `loader()` need to be declared final.

```
public void loader(JFrame browser, final JTextField url, final JEditorPane htmlc, JPanel header, JButton send, String[] arg)
    {
       ...
```

Besides that, please read up on [thread safety in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).  Almost your entire main method should be enclosed in a `Runnable` that gets executed on Swing's Event Dispatch Thread.

```
public static void main( String... args ) {

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {

         Jframe browser = new Jframe( "Nun in a wheelchair." );
         ...

      }
    });

}
```